# Custom Segue View Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a FirstViewController and SecondViewController. I made a "CustomSegue" between them.

Perform method in CustomSegue.

```
- (void)perform
{
    // Add your own animation code here.
    CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat offset = 60;

    UIView *sourceView = [self.sourceViewController view];
    UIView *destinationView = [self.destinationViewController view];

    destinationView.frame = CGRectMake(-width, 0, width-offset, height);

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window insertSubview:destinationView aboveSubview:sourceView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         sourceView.frame = CGRectOffset(sourceView.frame, width-offset, 0);
                         destinationView.frame = CGRectOffset(destinationView.frame, width, 0);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
                     }];
}
```

[image: Before Segue]    [image: After Segue]

Blue one is first view controller and green one is second view controller. I have initiated the segue from the center button of first view controller.

Now I wanted to unwind the segue from the "button" action from the second view controller (Green One). I linked the button to the unwind action in SecondViewController. But it crashes the app. shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS. without any error log in debugger.

When I uncomment the code in completion block. It will trigger the unwind action. But when I comment it it will crash the app. But if I uncomment the code in completion block. The view of second view controller take up the entire screen which is not what I wanted.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a segue here - you can simply manipulate the frames of the relevant views

Comment: Why not segues? I wanted to manipulate views of two different view controllers in a storyboard. Any other idea?

Comment: If you want to use segues then you will need to create a custom unwind segue as well

Comment: I have created it. And wanted to trigger unwind action through that button in second view controller.  But whenever I click the button. The app crashes.